# How is concatenation with the plus operator defined for String plus Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to assume that `"test=" + ['abc', 'xyz']` will produce `"test=abc,xyz"` for all JavaScript execution environments that follow standard?

Comment: Yes it internally uses `array.join(',')` which just concatenates the strings with `,` in between them. Result may differ when array elements are non-strings.

Comment: It depends what you consider "safe". `Array#toString` can be overridden with your own logic.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, "standard" has changed and will continue to change. The beauty of JS is that you still can add the `toString()` method as a shim for ol' environments. Note that your standard will change, you should precise it in the question so that it can last in time.

Comment: Also, [xkcd standards](https://xkcd.com/927/), just for the fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) I could confirm the expected behaviour, as long as `toString` is not overwritten:

[image: Screenshot from Spec]

`ToString` will be evaluated with `ToPrimitive` which in turn evaluates `OrdinaryToPrimitive` for the Array with the hint set to string which then finally calles the Arrays `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be safe 99% of the time but since it is JavaScript you should also expect monkey patching.

Even if you run in a safe environment, I would still opt for clarity:

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'xyz'];
const str = `test=${arr.join(',')}`;
```

*Why?*

1. The intent is clearer (IMHO)
2. People who don't know the inner workings of JavaScript can still understand that code

**What's up with the 1%?**

People can and *will* monkey patch JavaScript. Can you afford a risk there?

```js
Array.prototype.toString = () => '';

const arr = ['abc', 'xyz'];
const str = 'test=' + arr;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: If I am paranoid enough to expect that someone overwrite `Array.prototype.toString`, can I really rely on `Array.prototype.join` ;-)

Comment: Fair point. You can of course make that argument for every methods and functions. Just be aware that it is not unusual to override `toString()` though, especially when you need some custom serialisation logic.